# Twilio: Is there a way to export all opt outs?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to export everyone who has reply stop (opt out) for my messages. I see that my options are

1. API. However, through the API I can see that I get everything in pages of 50 messages, so I have to go and do a lot of code to go page by page, message by message just to check if the content is stop. Seems a bit unnecessary for a 1 time job.
2. From the console in my account, however when each time i try to filter on status received I get the following error, and when I dont filter I get error:
   *Your export request has more than 10,000 records, please filter your results and try again.*

[image]

Surely there must be an easy way that I can get all the list of numbers that had opt out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to export all opt-outs for LC's/TF's that Twilio maintains on your behalf but opt-outs are forwarded to your application for logging as well as added to the Twilio maintained opt-out list. Your application can keep track of the opt-outs this way. You can find more details in the Help Center article below.

[Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)

"When Twilio receives one of these replies, we will create a "blacklist" entry on our side, and then pass the message on to your webhook. Once we have a blacklist entry for a particular recipient phone number, any future attempts to message them will be met with a 400 response from our API, along with Error Code 21610 - Message cannot be sent to the 'To' number because the customer has replied with STOP. Recipients can disable this message stop, and resume receiving messages with the START, YES, or UNSTOP commands as outlined below."

Also, if you use the Twilio helper library for the respective language, it handles the paging for you, for example, for Node.js, reference.

[Usage and Migration Guide for Twilio's Node.js Helper Library 3.x](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node/usage-guide#paging)

"One of the biggest advantages of twilio-node 3.x is that it automatically handles paging for you! In both list and each, you can specify the maximum number of instances to grab (limit), and the page size (pageSize). The library will take care of everything else."

Comment: Thankyou, we have been using twilio for a couple of years now, and we dont have the webhook enable, so basically this means that the only way will be scrapping all the pages for those keywords?, our app is not node

Comment: No worries, here are the other helper libraries we have.
Server-Side SDKs - https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries. Also, if your app attempts to sends to a number that has opted-out, you will receive an error response from Twilio (Error Code 21610 - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610) in the debugger but also via the StatusCallback URL if you have it configured.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of it, and that is pretty cool, I just want to export this list and update our CRM and mark those numbers as unsubscribe, I am just quite surprise that this fucntionality is not availble from a click of a button inside twilio console

Comment: It is not, sorry about that.

Comment: Hopefully it will be in the roadmap, I think this is an important functionality to have :)

Comment: @Alan thank you for this reply, may I wonder what concrete webhook will be called if user unsubscribes from Messaging Service?
Is it statusCallbackUrl or inboundRequestUrl?

Comment: You will just look at the inbound Message Body (and the opt-out keywords - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-). Also, if you have Advanced Opt-out enabled for a Messaging Service, you will also get a mew key called `OptOutType` - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034798533-Getting-Started-with-Advanced-Opt-Out-for-Messaging-Services

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the insight. In our case, we are directing the incoming messages to Messaging service then to Studio flow via Flex Proxy. Well, opt-out works fine, but, as OptOutType parameter is not there in studio flow, we weren't able to check the message and make decision on basis of it. Similarly, if that customer is already opt-out, then also we want to know about its status.

Answer (score 5):

This answer above is not strictly true as of October 2020. Twilio now has an "insights" dashboard that allows you to view and download "Opt outs Received". When you click on that dashboard you are able to see and download the information.

It is under: Programmable Messaging -> Monitor -> Insights

[image]

Our account has "Opt-Out Management" enabled and this addition has been a game changer in finding out what users have or have not done in our system.

[image]

[image]